# Platform specific dependency in .net MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

I've tried to implement platform specific dependency for hide keyboard.

```
Platforms/Android/KeyboardHelper.cs

namespace MobileApp.Platforms.Android
{
    public static partial class KeyboardHelper
    {
        public static void HideKeyboard()
        {
            var context = Platform.AppContext;
            var inputMethodManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            if (inputMethodManager != null)
            {
                var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;
                var token = activity.CurrentFocus?.WindowToken;
                inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(token, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
                activity.Window.DecorView.ClearFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}

Platforms/iOS/KeyboardHelper.cs

namespace MobileApp.Platforms.iOS
{
    public static partial class KeyboardHelper
    {
        public static void HideKeyboard()
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().EndEditing(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I've resolved through dependency injection.
Register in app.xaml.cs
DependencyService.Register<IKeyboardHelper, MobileApp.Platforms.KeyboardHelper>();

and use it in when i need:

DependencyService.Get().HideKeyboard();

Comment: Well that looks like you've got a compile-time error... so what's the error? What's the rest of the context of the code that you've only shown us a screenshot of? Can you provide a complete but minimal class (as *text* rather than as an image) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated question. do you know why i'm not able to access iOS class method ?

Comment: You updated the question but without addressing any of the questions in my comment. (Or to give a level of detail in an answer that matches the detail of the question: "You need to fix your code." *Any* time you post a question that refers to the error, it's *vital* that you give the details of the error. "Facing compile time error" doesn't tell us what the error *is*. It's like going to the doctor and asking them to prescribe the right medicine based on only "I'm not feeling well.")

Comment: @JonSkeet you can see red line over there. if i write it in text. you can't see. that's why i added image.

Comment: I'm not able to access iOS class method that's the concern.

Comment: Do you believe the red squiggly line gives the complete information about what's wrong? You could easily describe in text where the problem occurs - or give us the screenshot but *also* a complete but minimal class... **and the compiler error details**. But if you're not going to provide more information, you shouldn't expect to receive any help, I'm afraid. (I'm certainly not going to fire up Visual Studio just to try to reproduce this in the *hope* that I can work out what compiler error you're facing...)

Comment: Posting error and code as images is highly discouraged on SO.  Please take the time to post the error as text and format it properly

Comment: @Jason never mind, i've resolved through dependency service. i've updated.

Comment: You should not be using DependencyServices in Maui, The correct way to go is using Partial classes or Handlers based on what you are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created two *different* classes:

- `MobileApp.Platforms.Android.KeyboardHelper`
- `MobileApp.Platforms.iOS.KeyboardHelper`

If you wanted platform-specific implementations of the *same* class, they would have to be in the same namespace.

###### Platforms/Android/KeyboardHelper.cs

```cs
namespace MobileApp
{
    public static partial class KeyboardHelper
    {
        public static void HideKeyboard()
        {
            // ... the Android implementation ...
        }
    }
}
```

###### Platforms/iOS/KeyboardHelper.cs

```cs
namespace MobileApp
{
    public static partial class KeyboardHelper
    {
        public static void HideKeyboard()
        {
            // ... the iOS implementation ...
        }
    }
}
```

With the above approach, you will need an implementation defined for every target you are compiling for, or you will need a default no-op implementationed defined somewhere.

Alternatively, you could create a single file for all implementations, leveraging conditional compilation directives:

###### KeyboardHelper.cs

```cs
namespace MobileApp
{
    public static class KeyboardHelper
    {
        public static void HideKeyboard()
        {
#if IOS
            // ... the iOS implementation ...
#elif ANDROID
            // ... the Android implementation ...
#else
            // ... the default implementation (if there is one) ...
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: If you want the iOS implementation to also apply to Mac Catalyst, you could use either `#if __IOS__` or you can use `#if IOS || MACCATALYST`.  They do the same thing.*

When invoking the code, you do not need to do a runtime check for platform.  Just call `KeyboardHelper.HideKeyboard()`.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code